# How to disable headphone detection?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones, speakers

In Windows there is an option to disable auto detection of headphones so speakers won't auto mute but I am unable to find such option in Ubuntu. How can I activate such feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a terminal type alsamixer, go to Automute via navigation keys, press up or down and set it to disable.
Unfortunately, you will still hear sound from your headphones.

Comment: Thank you big, I don't mind sound coming through both.  I wonder why that option isn't in any of the sound options and gui alsa mixers I've installed.