# How do I switch sound output to line out when headphones are plugged in?

Tags: sound

How can I force sound output on line out when headphones are plugged in? When I try to switch the output device to line out, sound only comes from the headphones as long as they're plugged in.

Comment: Ah, a different search found the answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/367686/how-to-disable-headphone-detection

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing and running pavucontrol. It's a tool that allows you to control the playback, input devices, **output devices** (which probably is what you're looking for) and much more.

- Open terminal and enter the following command:

> sudo apt install pavucontrol

- You can now open it from Dash. Go to **Output Devices** tab and from
  there, you can choose the port which the sound will be coming out
  from.

[image]

Despite having a plugged headphone, you can now choose the output device from where the computer sound will come out.
This tool has already helped me a lot with Stereo Mixing issues and sound output as well. Try taking a look on the Configurations tab too and see if it suits your needs.